# using system() for executing a command return -1

Tags: c, pthreads

I need to create a thread that its job is to check existence of a executable file by calling that every T seconds.

I used `system()` function. When I execute this part of code as an independent program, it works well, but when I put it into my main program, which is a big one, the `system()` function returns -1.

Even when I call "ls /etc/" the return value of system() is -1 !

Comment: Check `errno` -- [`man system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) points to [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), where this and the possible errors are listed.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `system` for this when there are perfectly good library calls that do what you need, e.g. [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

Comment: but i run this program, exactly the same as what i put in the main project, and it works. i create a thread using pthrea_create, and as its (thread's) main work, i call system! even calling system("ls /etc/") returns -1 in the main project!! remember that, the situation from this point that both of them using thread and system() is the same

Comment: You really should check the value of `errno` immediately after `system()` failed.

Comment: Please don't check for the existence of an executable by trying to invoke it every X seconds.  Instead, use fstat() as @PaulR suggested.  It's a far better approach, and about a million times more efficient.

Comment: system() from thread? Monsieur knows a lot about perversions.

Comment: just as a question, is it possible to check existence of a folder using fstat() too?

Comment: I'm not sure that `PATH` is set up. try `system("/bin/ls /etc/")`

Comment: @zhuan: yes, [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) works for both directories and files - you can use the `S_ISDIR` macros to test the `st_mode` field to determine whether a path leads to a a directory.

Comment: thanks @PaulR, fstat works ;)

Comment: @zhuan: "*just as a question, is it possible to check existence of a folder using fstat() too?*" As some kind guy/s here already provided a link to the relevant documenation, please be so kind and RTFM!

Comment: `system()` does `fork()`! Forking in multithreaded process is asking for bad things to happen!